# The returned hash from fetch_hash in Mail::IMAPClient doesn't meet the parameters I send

Tags: perl, imapclient

This is a auto answered question about a problem I had and I found no answer, the problem is the following:

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;
$imap = new Mail::IMAPClient(
   # My connection data.
};
#Folder selection and stuff like that.
my $hash = $imap->fetch_hash('BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]');
```

Now I have a hash with the subject of the emails in the folder I selected, I had expected it to return the subject of a message writing:

```
print $hash->{mymessage}->{'BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]'};
```

Instead I got:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/localhost/htdocs/user/mail.pl line 76.

Please excuse my poor english.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) This is the kind of problem I always enjoy at work: one that solves itself :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was seeing what `keys $hash->{mymessage}`
was returning, it was `BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]`, so I figured out Mail::IMAPClient, omit PEEK from any call to the function while creating the hash keys in the function fetch_hash().
What I should did is:

```
print $hash->{mymessage}->{'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]'};`
```